# There is already an object named 'X' in the database. But there isn't

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

When I try run a simple create table script I get the "there is already an object..." error. Then when I run the select:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id (N'[dbo].[tableX]')
```

There are no rows returned.

Here is what my create script looks like:

```
USE [DB]
GO   

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableX](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [colA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [colB] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [colC] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,    
    [colD] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [colE] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [tableX] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it seems that you are trying to create a `CONSTRAINT` with the exact same name as your table.

`CONSTRAINT [tableX] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

Change it for something like:

`CONSTRAINT [pk_tableX] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`

Comment: I wish MS would be slightly more helpful with the errors so nobody has to end up here. (Yes we probably all could have figured it out eventually.)